# Using TwitterAPI with Symfony

Tags: api, symfony

I need to create simple app that uses TwitterAPI to fetch users and their tweets and saves them to local database.

How do i "implement" the fetching part?I never used API's in framework(only vanilla javascript),so i'm confused how to do it in framework(Symfony3).I know I need to register on twitter to get api keys,but what to do next?Kinda confused didn't find nothing on how to use Twitter API in Symfony...

Comment: Twitter offers several SDKs (for PHP as well as Javascript).  If you're going the PHP route with Symfony, I'd pick one you can manage with Composer.  As far as what do to after you get your API key... Read the documentation... and try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, twitter has an [api documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs), one simple search got me to [this](https://gonzalo123.com/2013/02/04/how-to-configure-symfonys-service-container-to-use-twitter-api/) so there is some material you just didn't search well.

I used [this library](https://twitteroauth.com/) before it has good documentation and you can just include it and use in your project or I just now found [this](https://github.com/endroid/Twitter) a Symfony bundle for twitter, this should also help you.